# Passing an argument to a function in a different script?

Tags: python, terminal

I have a script called `test.py` and inside that script I have the following:

```
class TestClass:

    def greetings(name):

        print "Hello %s!" % name
        return;


    def oppositeBool(value):

        if value == True:
            return False;
        else:
            return True;
```

In terminal I do the following to import it:

```
$ python
>>> import test
```

How do I run a method now? I'd like to do the following:

```
test.greetings('Superman')
```

and:

```
myNewValue = test.oppositeBool(True)
print myNewValue
```

Comment: Looks like those functions are in the `TestClass` class, so you'll have to access that class.

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3 and how would I do that? Sorry I'm fairly new to python coming from Objective-C : )

Comment: ``test.TestClass.greetings('Superman')`` or ``from test import TestClass``. Then you can do something like ``TestClass.greetings('Superman')``

Comment: Have you tried reading some of Python's documentation or the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: Just finished the codecademy course, but I figure that's a good next step!

Comment: I see a lot of questions here from people who have done that course. It doesn't seem very good.

Comment: Yeah I think it shows you the basics, but not enough to actually go ahead and do real-world stuff.

Comment: After trying the first couple "lessons," I'm disappointed to see that it doesn't complain about excessive semicolons (Python statements do not need to end with a semicolon), and Python 3 isn't even mentioned. I can see why it pops up so frequently here.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that. Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these function are in a class, so you need call the function like this:

```
import test
c = test.TestClass()
c.greetings('Superman')
```

Sure. If you really want to call the function like `test.greetings('Superman')`, don't define it in a class.

---

And by the way, a function in a class must with a `self` variable like this:

```
def greetings(self, name):

    print "Hello %s!" % name
    return
```

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately I'm seeing the following: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TestClass' is not defined`

Comment: Totally forgot `self`! Thank you very much